# Manipulação de arquivos de texto temporário

Tags: delphi-10

Estou tentando manipular um arquivo de texto no meu sistema, nele terá que conter o nome da maquina que os sistema está sendo executado. Só que eu não estou conseguindo Escrever no tal arquivo.

**Ps:** *O intuito desse arquivo não é salvar o texto, é ter o texto nele até o sistema ser fechado.*

Abaixo vou deixar o código de como eu crio e tento escrever no arquivo, e só na saída do sistema eu Fecho o arquivo.

```
// Aqui o Autosad cria os arquivos de Controle de Usuário
for I := 1 to QuantUsuarios do
begin
  NomeArq := DM.tbParamPASTA_BD.AsString+'\Controle'+IntToStr(I)+'.txt';
  // Verificando se o arquivo existe
  if not FileExists(nomeArq) then
  begin
    NomeMaquina := 'Controle: '+CompName; // CompName é uma função que pega o nome da maquina.
    AssignFile(Arq, NomeArq); 
    Rewrite(Arq);             
    Writeln(Arq,NomeMaquina); 
    Break;
  end;

  if I >= QuantUsuarios then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Erro ao tentar Criar o arquivo de Controle!'+#13+'Acione o SUPORTE!!');
    // Encerra o Sistema
    DMl.db_AutoSad.Connected := False;
    frmEntradaSistema.close;
  end;
end;
```

esse código eu adaptei de vários sites que eu pesquisei.
se tiver algum outro modo de fazer ficaria agradecido se poderem explicar.

Comment: Se você não pretende salvar o arquivo, apenas manter os dados durante a execução do programa, não precisa criar um arquivo. Pode manter os dados, por exemplo, em um StrigngList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa Tudo bem!
**Provavelmente** você não consegue ver o conteúdo do arquivo porque não está salvo.

Velho você pode fazer assim, depois de `Writeln(Arq,NomeMaquina);` você fechar o arquivo, isso vai salvar o texto no disco. depois reabre o arquivo com `Reset(Arq);`. Ai você vai poder visualizar o que está dentro do arquivo e ou modificar se for de sua vontade ai na hora que fechar o seu sistema você apaga.

> **Reset();** Prepara um arquivo existente para leitura e coloca o ponteiro
>   de arquivo no início. Caso o arquivo não exista, esta instrução
>   provocará um erro de Entrada/Saída (*Input*/*Output*).

```
// Verificando se o arquivo existe
if not FileExists(nomeArq) then
begin
  AssignFile(Arq, NomeArq);
  Rewrite(Arq);
  Writeln(Arq, CompName);
  CloseFile(Arq);
  AssignFile(Arq, NomeArq);
  Reset(Arq);
  Break;
end;
```